Meaning of "sinc" at the very beginning of the Introduction section
What is the meaning of sinc at the very beginning of the Introduction section of a thesis?
I believe that it is not a typo, I checked it on various websites but I couldn't find anything except the sinc function.

Here's the link to the PDF.

Why do you believe it's not a typo? I'm pretty sure it is.

@MichaelHarvey: I'd guess probably not an actual typo, but a typesetting command that was not supposed to be printed.,

My guess is that there was meant to be an equation there, but the math symbols didn’t take, leaving just the “sinc” part of the equation...

Your guess is quite plausible! It could result from an attempt to include a mathematical expression. Thank you Mr. Hat, Mr. Shor, and Mr. Harvey. Your comments are so helpful to grasp this mystery.

There is a function called sinc: sinc(x) = sin(x)/x. I can easily imagine a cut and paste error in the LaTeX markup for the paper.
